# AWS Data Pipeline Backup RDS PSQL Data to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I tried using AWS DATA Pipeline to transfer data from PSQL to S3, however my activities are failing due to memory issue. I am getting Java heap space error

What are the multiple solution through which I can transfer data from psql table ( 25 Gb ) to S3.
Is launching high memory machine the only option ?

Ronak

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, psql table mean Postgres database table.

I am not sure, why this backup activity or transferring data needs to happen in your front end.

The way we implemented to take a backup of table into a CSV file is using [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command. You can execute that from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Vira . I am aware of the copy command. I have 2- 25 Gb, and 3- 40 Gb tables. Need to put them to S3. The EC2 Instance which I am currently using doesnot copy the data as it  required high memory. So I tried using AWS DataPipeline.

Comment: @ronakAgrawal which instance class you are using?

Comment: T2.Medium .I though AWS Pipeline was streaming the data into S3